Getting XRD data from pymatgen, not the plot
I am working on pymatgen XRD calculator Jupyter Notebook, everything is OK. I plot XRD pattern for a specific structure. But I do not know how to export calculation results in .cif format.
I did not try anything. I think it is a basic command issue. Naturally, I cannot find the right commands and syntax just by trial and error. After defining the structure, and importing necessary components of Python, the following last 3 lines of the script works well.
The first line probably performs the calculation, the second one plots the data and the third one just gives crystal parameters.
c = XRDCalculator()
ax = c.get_plot(structure)
print(structure)

How can I get the XRD data in .cif format?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

This sounds like all you lack is a plt.show() at the end, forcing your plot to, well, show.

Thanks for correction. I edited my last sentence.
